# Can't Clear "Form and Search History" in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, web-browser

I am attempting to clear the "form & search history" in Firefox, and the box is completely grayed out and will not allow me access.

[image]

Any thoughts or suggestions about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the item (in your are the "Form & Search History") is already cleared.

Are you sure this is not your case?

---

You mentioned in you comment that Firefox autofills the search bar when you type a website. Do you mean the URL bar (also known as *Awesome bar* ) ?

If yes, then the described behavior is expected. [The Awesome bar get its results from "bookmarks, history and tabs"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-find-your-bookmarks-history-and-tabs).

So if you want to remove urls that you previously typed, you have to clear your browser's history.

---

On the other hand, if you mean the actual search-bar:
 [image]

Then right click on it and select "Clear Search History" or select the option you mention in the question.

On the image above the "stack" word is a search I have previously done. You probably don't have any, since they are cleared.

For more information on what each option on the "Clear Recent History..." means check [this section](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox#w_what-things-are-included-in-my-history).

Comment: I don't believe so, because Firefox is still autofilling the search bar when I type in websites.

Comment: There is probably some confusion between the search bar and the url bar. Edited my asnwer. Check and let me know :-)

Comment: thank you! your additional link is what helped me find my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The add-on BetterPrivacy is interfering, when this add-on is disabled, you can clear history again. It is reported at Bugzilla per Juli 2015, hopefully someone is working on it there...